# SignalR return string from server to client

Tags: javascript, java, android, signalr

I´m calling a function from my client to generate an ID on the SignalR server.

The SignalR function:

```
public string generateID() {
  String id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  return id;
}
```

It´s working fine from a JavaScript Client like this:

```
hub.server.generateID().done(function (result) {
            var id = result;
            console.log(result);
        });
```

But I can't retrieve the generated ID from my Android client.

```
String id = hub.invoke("generateID");
```

The return value is always void instead of String as returned on the server side. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in android its called :

```
  hub.invoke(String.class, "generateID").done(new Action<String>() {
      @Override
      public void run(String ExternalID) throws Exception {

      }
```

Comment: there is a closing bracket ")" missing at the end, but otherwise its perfect, thank you