How to get return string from task on signalr server in android studio java project?
I have task on signalR server as :
public string test(string teststr)
    {
        string test = "Data Source=sql.bsite.net\\MSSQL2016;Initial Catalog=rushihardware_Erpsolution;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=rushihardware_Erpsolution;Password=Abcd@1999626" ;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(test);
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            test = "done";
            con.Close();
        }

        return test;
    }

How can I received return value in my android java client?
I try answer from link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341137/signalr-return-string-from-server-to-client][1]
but I got error: Cannot resolve symbol 'done'
How can I solved?
Thanks in advance!!
